# Ubuntu 11.04 not updating

Tags: updates, update-manager

I have a 11.04 running on my PC.

It is not able to upgrade either through the GUI or terminal.

It simply  does not show the option of upgrading, it simply says no updates available.

Comment: What happens when you type `sudo apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade`? Please post the exact output of that command. Normally, "no updates available" means that your system is up to date, and all updates that were needed are already installed.

Answer (score 0):

Try these commands:

```
sudo apt-get update -fmy
sudo apt-get upgrade -fmy
```